# Select statement using 'EXISTS' and 'IN' operator

Tags: sql, query

I hit an issue to get data using 'IN' operator from another database. I need help fixing this please.

**My query looks like this:**

```
SELECT i.EXTERNAL_CODE, tc.SITE_NAME, tr.TRANSACTION_DT
  FROM app4_starlims_data.dbo.INVENTORY i
       JOIN app4_starlims_data.dbo.VA_TUBE_COLLECTION tc
          ON tc.INVENTORYID = i.INVENTORYID
       JOIN app4_starlims_data.dbo.INVENTORY_TRANSACTIONS it
          ON it.INVENTORYID = i.INVENTORYID
       JOIN app4_starlims_data.dbo.transactions tr
          ON tr.TRANSACTION_ID = it.TRANSACTION_ID
 WHERE i.EXTERNAL_CODE IN
          (SELECT vacutainer_ref, quality, [timestamp]
             FROM dna_lab_biospecimen.dbo.blood_sample
            WHERE     quality LIKE '%under%'
                  AND [timestamp] BETWEEN '02-19-2021' AND '03-07-2021')
```

**The error I get is:**

> Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Only one expression can be
> specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
> EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a subquery with an `IN` operator within a `WHERE` clause which only allows one column value to be returned. Adjust the subquery's `SELECT` statement column to only be the one that needs returned (e.g. `vacutainer_ref`).

### SQL Query

```
SELECT i.EXTERNAL_CODE
    ,tc.SITE_NAME
    ,tr.TRANSACTION_DT
FROM app4_starlims_data.dbo.INVENTORY i
JOIN app4_starlims_data.dbo.VA_TUBE_COLLECTION tc ON tc.INVENTORYID = i.INVENTORYID
JOIN app4_starlims_data.dbo.INVENTORY_TRANSACTIONS it ON it.INVENTORYID = i.INVENTORYID
JOIN app4_starlims_data.dbo.transactions tr ON tr.TRANSACTION_ID = it.TRANSACTION_ID
WHERE i.EXTERNAL_CODE IN (
        SELECT vacutainer_ref
        FROM dna_lab_biospecimen.dbo.blood_sample
        WHERE quality LIKE '%under%'
            AND [timestamp] BETWEEN '02-19-2021'
                AND '03-07-2021'
        );
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Subquery rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15#rules)

  > A subquery is subject to the following restrictions:
  >
  > - The select list of a subquery introduced with a comparison operator
  >   can include only one expression or column name (except that `EXISTS` and
  >   `IN` operate on `SELECT *` or a list, respectively).
  > - Because they must return a single value, subqueries introduced by an unmodified comparison operator (one not followed by the keyword `ANY`
  >   or `ALL`) cannot include `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses
  > - The select list of a subquery introduced with `EXISTS`, by convention, has an asterisk (`*`) instead of a single column name. The
  >   rules for a subquery introduced with `EXISTS` are the same as those
  >   for a standard select list, because a subquery introduced with
  >   `EXISTS` creates an existence test and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`,
  >   instead of data.

Comment: Thanks, I realized it after I submitted ticket. When I changed my query and used only one row in a subquery ... everything worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard my question:

My fault was that I didn't realize that subquery returns multiple rows.